# GSM Module CME Error code 15

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, gsm, sim-card

I am attempting to build a GSM/MCU project using a ADH8066 GSM module.

I have managed to setup a reliable serial comm with the unit, but now I am struggling with the sim card integration.

I am trying to make sense of the response: "+CME ERROR: 15" when attempting a "AT+CPIN?" command.

When the sim card is not present I receive +CME ERROR: 10 which is expected (SIM not inserted), but when sim is inserted and module is rebooted I get this 15 error. Can anybody advise me on what this means?

The Sim cards I have tried are South African sims registered on the Vodacom and Mtn networks here in SA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+CME ERROR:15 tends to be because the modem can't work with the SIM card. This is usually the case with UMTS only network SIM cards.

ADH8066 GSM module is the evaluation board. But what is the modem you have integrated? Would be useful to know as then you can verify if its a simple GSM modem (which is what I am assuming).

As a side note the +CME ERROR: 10 error is based on whether the SIM card "door" is closed or not. It does not tell you whether all is good with the SIM card or not. Hence the differing error codes.

Answer (score 2):

Here are meaning of ALL error codes :

```
# Error Code
CME ERROR: 0     Phone failure
CME ERROR: 1     No connection to phone
CME ERROR: 2     Phone adapter link reserved
CME ERROR: 3     Operation not allowed
CME ERROR: 4     Operation not supported
CME ERROR: 5     PH_SIM PIN required
CME ERROR: 6     PH_FSIM PIN required
CME ERROR: 7     PH_FSIM PUK required
CME ERROR: 10     SIM not inserted
CME ERROR: 11     SIM PIN required
CME ERROR: 12     SIM PUK required
CME ERROR: 13     SIM failure
CME ERROR: 14     SIM busy
CME ERROR: 15     SIM wrong
CME ERROR: 16     Incorrect password
CME ERROR: 17     SIM PIN2 required
CME ERROR: 18     SIM PUK2 required
CME ERROR: 20     Memory full
CME ERROR: 21     Invalid index
CME ERROR: 22     Not found
CME ERROR: 23     Memory failure
CME ERROR: 24     Text string too long
CME ERROR: 25     Invalid characters in text string
CME ERROR: 26     Dial string too long
CME ERROR: 27     Invalid characters in dial string
CME ERROR: 30     No network service
CME ERROR: 31     Network timeout
CME ERROR: 32     Network not allowed, emergency calls only
CME ERROR: 40     Network personalization PIN required
CME ERROR: 41     Network personalization PUK required
CME ERROR: 42     Network subset personalization PIN required
CME ERROR: 43     Network subset personalization PUK required
CME ERROR: 44     Service provider personalization PIN required
CME ERROR: 45     Service provider personalization PUK required
CME ERROR: 46     Corporate personalization PIN required
CME ERROR: 47     Corporate personalization PUK required
CME ERROR: 48     PH-SIM PUK required
CME ERROR: 100     Unknown error
CME ERROR: 103     Illegal MS
CME ERROR: 106     Illegal ME
CME ERROR: 107     GPRS services not allowed
CME ERROR: 111     PLMN not allowed
CME ERROR: 112     Location area not allowed
CME ERROR: 113     Roaming not allowed in this location area
CME ERROR: 126     Operation temporary not allowed
CME ERROR: 132     Service operation not supported
CME ERROR: 133     Requested service option not subscribed
CME ERROR: 134     Service option temporary out of order
CME ERROR: 148     Unspecified GPRS error
CME ERROR: 149     PDP authentication failure
CME ERROR: 150     Invalid mobile class
CME ERROR: 256     Operation temporarily not allowed
CME ERROR: 257     Call barred
CME ERROR: 258     Phone is busy
CME ERROR: 259     User abort
CME ERROR: 260     Invalid dial string
CME ERROR: 261     SS not executed
CME ERROR: 262     SIM Blocked
CME ERROR: 263     Invalid block
CME ERROR: 772     SIM powered down
```